# YUTorah's old site?

Tags: internet

YUTorah.org is a website that contains over 100,000 shiurim from many rabbeim . They redid their website, but would anyone know how I can access the old site still?

Comment: The old shiurim are still accessible on the redone website. What are you missing that needs the old version?

Comment: I think I will have an easier time on the old one

Comment: I had a similar issue with the mobile site when they started redirecting to the new one - the old one was actually easier to use for some things (more direct access to daf yomi shiurim, for instance)

Answer (score 4):

[classic.yutorah.org](http://classic.yutorah.org/)

My work blocks the new version but allows the old version.